# Pandas - Convert multiple Series having multiple columns to Dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

How can I convert Series to DataFrame?

The problem is mapping columns' name of Series and DataFrame

I have a Series like this:

(made with groupby and concat function)

```
CUS_ID  DAY
2       MON    0.176644
        TUE    0.246489
        WED    0.160569
        THU    0.234109
        FRI    0.170916
...
dtype: float64
```

And what I want to get is like this:

```
CUS_ID  MON       TUE       WED       THU       FRI
2       0.176644  0.246489  0.160569  0.234109  0.170916
```

The type must be DataFrame..!

Is there any way to get it without using 'for' statement??

Comment: you need df.unstack()~

Comment: Oh my god, It works! thanks a lot!!

Answer (score 1):

You can simply unstack the index

```
s=pd.Series(data=[1,2,3,4,5],index=[[2,2,2,2,2],['mon','tue','wed','thu','fri']])
2  mon    1
   tue    2
   wed    3
   thu    4
   fri    5

s.unstack()
    fri mon thu tue wed
2   5   1   4   2   3
```